# for loops in excel (bash equivalent)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am working with a large database in excel. I have to calculate average scores across specific cells. The numerical value in the cells (and by a cell i mean A4, D5 etc.), however, does not correspond to the value that needs to be added by to calculate the score. So far I have been using something like this:

```
=(sum(if(A1=1,3,IF(A1=2,2,IF(A1=3,1,IF(A1=4,0,"NA")))))+
+IF(F1=1,2,IF((F=2,2,IF(F=3,1,IF(F=4,0,"NA")))))+IF(....
```

and so on. Where a cell that contains 1 contributes 3 to the total score, a cell that contains 2 - 2, a cell that contains 3 to 1 etc.

However, I am sure that there should be a quicker and cleaner way of computing this. Is there a way that a similar structure as the one below could be used in excel?

```
for A1,AB1,AC1...[the desired cells); do; 
 if $column=1,3
 if $column=3,1
 if $column=4,0 ; done
```

Thanks for you help in advance!

Best,
R

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `For ... Next` loop over the cells you are attempting to iterate, and conditional logic to assign the "score" based on the value.  The loop is a little trickier for non-contiguous cells like what you have.

I would create a delimited string and then use the `Split` function to convert that to an array, over which you can iterate, assigning to a `Range` object to represent each cell in the iteration.

```
Dim cellsList as String
Dim cells as Variant
Dim c as Variant
Dim cl as Range
Dim score as Integer
Dim totalScore as Integer
Dim naCount as Integer
cellsList = "A1,AB1,AC1" 'Modify as needed

'convert delimited string to an array:
cells = Split(cellsList, ",")
For each c in cells
    Set cl = Range(c)
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case 1
            score = 3
        Case 2
            naCount = naCount + 1 'keep track of these since they will not be included in the mean score
        Case 3
            score = 1
        Case 4
            score = 0
    End Select

    totalScore = totalScore + score
Next
'Display the average score:
MsgBox totalScore / ((UBound(cells) + 1) - naCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

The score it's like **4-value** then if you want to use only EXCEL:
Create a name for the selected cells you want to add (no necessary near...). (Sample xx).
Insert in a cell the formula:

```
=4*COUNT(xx)-SUM(xx)
```